# Grep [[:punct:]] Doesn't Capture Punctuation

Tags: bash

I am trying to test the `[[:punct:]]` character class.  According to the `grep` manual it states that all these characters are considered punctuation:

`'[:punct:]'`
Punctuation characters; in the ‘C’ locale and ASCII character encoding, this is

```
! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ _ ` { | } ~."
```

So I tried with a comma:

```
$ cat testfile 
SANDWITCH
bread
103 mayo
,cant get this line to match with punct
$ grep [[punct:]] testfile 
$
```

Doesn't give any results.  I was expecting the last line in the file to print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a colon:

```
$ grep '[[:punct:]]' testfile 
#         ^
```

not

```
$ grep [[punct:]] testfile
```

Comment: Oh man, it's so obvious sorry!  I've been playing around this topic most of today, getting tired, my bad.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @johnsmith Also, be sure to quote the pattern -- without quotes, the shell will try to expand it as a filename wildcard before passing it to `grep`, and if it finds any matches the results tend to be bizarre.